# Change widget model from parent in Elm

Tags: random, composition, elm, message

I am using the ["compose" pattern](https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en-v01/02-elm-arch/06-composing.html) in Elm.

In `Main.elm`, I am generating an initial seed for `Random` using the following:

```
type alias Model =
    { ...
    , seed : Seed
    }

initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { ...
    , seed = initialSeed 0
    }

init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( initialModel, generate InitializeSeed (int minInt maxInt) )

type Msg
    = ...
    | InitializeSeed Int

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ...

        InitializeSeed value ->
            ( { model | seed = Random.initialSeed value }, Cmd.none )
```

which seems to work well for initializing the random number generator seed to a random starting value.

I have an "independent" widget that is used in the main application. I would like to pass the seed down to that widget on receipt of the `InitializeSeed` message and then retrieve the value as it changes in the child widget (using `Random.step`) so that I can then update other widgets' seeds as they need the generator.

How can I generate a message for the child widget from the `update` function in `Main` so that I can pass the seed down to the child? How can the child return the updated seed back to the parent?

**UPDATE:**

I figured out how to pass the seed down to the child widget, although I am not certain that this is best way.

The child code looks like this:

```
type alias Model =
    { ...
    , seed : Seed
    }

replaceSeed : Model -> Seed -> Model
replaceSeed model seed =
    { model | seed = seed }
```

and in the parent, I modified the `update` function like this:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ...
        InitializeSeed value ->
            let
                seed =
                    Random.initialSeed value

                child_ =
                    Child.replaceSeed model.child seed
            in
                ( { model
                    | seed = seed
                    , child = child_
                  }
                , Cmd.none
                )
```

I am still looking for a way to have the child return the updated seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the top level update function in any Elm program **must** be

```
update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
```

there are no limitations on the shape of any of its descendents.  So nothing prevents you defining for your child

```
update : Seed -> Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg, Seed)
```

or, if the child never returns any commands

```
update : Seed -> Msg -> Model -> (Model, Seed)
```

Maybe you have several things to pass down, including for example a parent message. Then you could go as far as

```
type alias Config msg = 
    { seed : Seed 
    , someParentMessage : String -> msg 
    }

update : Config msg -> Msg -> Model -> (Model, Maybe (Cmd msg), Seed)
```

You need to wire these all up appropriately in Main of course, but the compiler will help with that.